# Display the result with "null" at the beginning

Tags: java

I would like my programme displays the result without "null". I understand that when I sum up str1 + str2, str1 equals null that is why the result is incorrect, but I don't know how to solve it.

```
static String str1;
static String str2;
public static void ConvertBinaryArrayToInt(List<Integer> binary) {
    for (int i = 0; i<binary.size(); i++ ){
        int c = binary.get(i);
        str2 = String.valueOf(c);
        str1 = str1 + str2;
    }
    System.out.println(str1);    
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    List<Integer> binary1 = new ArrayList<>(4); 
    binary1.add(0,1 );
    binary1.add(1,0 );
    binary1.add(2,1 );
    binary1.add(3,1 );
    BinaryArrayToNumber.ConvertBinaryArrayToInt(binary1);
}
```

Comment: just initialize str1 as follow: `static String str1 = "";`

Comment: Are you sure your program does what you want it to do? The plus '+' symbol in Strings actually concatenates the strings (it does not sum up the int values). Not sure if that was your intention, or converting a binary number to a decimal number, since you use the term "sum up" in the description.

Comment: As a matter of readability and avoiding bugs, always, *always* initialize your variables. Java assigns default values to fields (including static fields) and hence lets you get away without initializing them explicitly, but my suggestion is you don’t rely on that.

Comment: @LucaNicoletti  thank you:)

Comment: @vefthym I could be wrong using the term "sum up". My programme should  get 4 components from Arraylist and convert it into String ([1,1,1,0] should be "1110") I hope my question was right :)

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you!

Comment: @Sabina did it work?

Comment: @LucaNicoletti sorry that didn't answer you immediately. Yes, it worked:)

Answer (score 1):

A very small way to solve it would be to do

```
str1 = (str1 == null ? "" : str1) + (str2 == null ? "" : str2);
```

However, you should create a method for this instead

```
private String safeConcatenate(String str1 String str2) {
    if (str1 == null && str2 == null)
        return "";
    if (str1 == null)
        return str2;
    if (str2 == null)
        return str1;
    return str1 + str2;
}
```

If you don't need to keep the variables the same, then this should also work:

```
private String safeConcatenate(String str1, String str2) {
    if (str1 == null)
        str1 = "";
    if (str2 == null)
        str2 = "";
    return str1 + str2;
}
```

Comment: Small typo: in the second code part, in: "if (stt2 == null)" should be "str2".

Comment: "If you don't need to keep the variables the same" -- this qualifier doesn't make sense. Reassigning local variables inside a method has no effect on variables outside the method.

Comment: @khelwood I imagine he's doing something else too that should go in these functions, but without further context, I don't know..

Comment: Since `str2` comes out of `String.valueOf(c)`, it is never `null`. The question also only asked about `str1` being null. `str1` is a static variable and just needs to be initialized (to non-null). Luca Nicotelli’s comments gives the effective yet simple solution.